# Corroded Metal vs Magical Armor, should it melt it?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monsters, balance, armor

The DM in our game homebrewed something called a Dire Otter Swarm and had the Corroded Metal attribute that can destroy nonmagical items, but he gave it a buff that allowed them to destroy *Magical* Items, to which the rest of our party gave him a confused look. Are we just being excessively sensitive about losing powerful items now or is that something that shouldn't have happened?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] for further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: It may be interesting to learn why the DM made this decision -- maybe he thinks your party has too many magic items, or maybe he plans to give you new ones once the arc is resolved.

Answer (score 31):

### If your DM is homebrewing things, then they do whatever the DM says they do.

If that's ruining your enjoyment of the game, you should take that up with the DM in a social context. As far as the rules go, the DM makes the final call on how abilities work, and that can include degrading or destroying magical items.

Comment: If you're feeling up to it, I think some guidelines/advice for how to take it up with the DM would be a fantastic addition to this answer. Especially how do your take that conversations without appearing "butthurt"?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is a good place for that. That would be better off being the topic of a separate question (which may have been asked before, but I can't find one right now)

Comment: You could quote from the [DMG](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#AddingaSpecialTrait) on creating or modifying monsters: "You can add a special trait of your own devising or pick up a special trait from one of the many creatures in the Monster Manual."

Comment: I suppose it depends how reliably/quickly the monster can destroy a magic item to whether this needs a discussion with your DM. It doesn't really make sense for magic items to be indestructible but we are hard-wired to feel loss way more than satisfaction from gain.